# TO_DATE error in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_person 
WHERE to_date(date_create, 'dd/mm/yyyy') < to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I hit the following error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

To be clear, `date_create` field stored `SYSDATE` when I added into table. What I need is to retrieve data from `tbl_person` table starting from 01/01/2010 onward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to call TO_DATE on a DATE.  Just use the date column in the query (and compare it to a date)

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_person
 WHERE date_created < to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```